# full screen width breadcrumb in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show full screen width breadcrumb to my website as step 1 step 2 step 3. with arrow and also need to show images near step 1.

But the problem is ,breadcrumbs is displaying only half of the screen.

```css
/** The Magic **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid rgb(173, 173, 173);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
/** The Spacing **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn {
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 24px;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:first-child {
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 10px;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:last-child {
  padding: 6px 18px 6px 24px;
}
/** Default button **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #fff;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #ebebeb;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #adadad;
}
/** Primary button **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-primary:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #428bca;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-primary:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #357ebd;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-primary:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #3276b1;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-primary:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #285e8e;
}
/** Success button **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-success:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #5cb85c;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-success:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #4cae4c;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-success:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #47a447;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-success:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #398439;
}
/** Danger button **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-danger:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #d9534f;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-danger:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #d43f3a;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-danger:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #d2322d;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-danger:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #ac2925;
}
/** Warning button **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-warning:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #f0ad4e;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-warning:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #eea236;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-warning:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #ed9c28;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-warning:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #d58512;
}
/** Info button **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-info:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #5bc0de;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-info:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #46b8da;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-info:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #39b3d7;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-info:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #269abc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb">

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The bootstrap container class has a fixed width on desktop screen sizes (above 768px). Therefore you need to either place your breadcrubs outside of the container element like so:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 4</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <!-- other content -->
</div>
```

or you apply the negative margin trick to the `.btn-breadcrumb` div:

```
.btn-breadcrumb {
  margin-right: calc(50% - 50vw);
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
  /* ... */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 3</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The 50% left margin moves your element to the center of the screen, minus 50vw is the left corner of the screen. The same thing goes for the right side and your element is fullscreen, even though it is placed inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of `flexbox` magic.

```css
.btn-group{
  display: flex;
}

.btn-breadcrumb .btn {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

/** The Magic **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid rgb(173, 173, 173);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
/** The Spacing **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn {
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 24px;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:first-child {
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 10px;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:last-child {
  padding: 6px 18px 6px 24px;
}
/** Default button **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #fff;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #ebebeb;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #adadad;
}
/** Primary button **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-primary:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #428bca;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-primary:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #357ebd;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-primary:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #3276b1;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-primary:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #285e8e;
}
/** Success button **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-success:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #5cb85c;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-success:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #4cae4c;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-success:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #47a447;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-success:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #398439;
}
/** Danger button **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-danger:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #d9534f;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-danger:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #d43f3a;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-danger:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #d2322d;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-danger:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #ac2925;
}
/** Warning button **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-warning:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #f0ad4e;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-warning:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #eea236;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-warning:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #ed9c28;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-warning:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #d58512;
}
/** Info button **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-info:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #5bc0de;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-info:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #46b8da;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-info:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #39b3d7;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-info:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #269abc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb">

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">STEP 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```